# What is the meaning of "when three sources tell you the same thing word for word, you know they're lying"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Mason getting ready to document dangerous place so before leaving she talks to Jerry on phone.

> Jerry: I don't get it. Why do you want a gig documenting a mapping
>   mission when you're up for the cover of Time?
>
> Mason: Jerry, **when three sources tell you the same thing word for
>   word, you know they're lying**. There's something going on here, 
>   something that nobody is talking about

Suppose I am new to place I ask three to four people where lodge is locate to rent & live here. I vote for majority here, then how three sources tell you the same thing word for word means lying instead of truth?

Comment: Do you understand what the phrase "word for word" means exactly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would not apply to guiding you to the bathroom. It refers to a criminal investigation.

When three people *independently* tell you about a thing and tell the truth, they will - given a reasonably long story - *never* use the *exact same words* (this is what *word by word* means).

If they tell the same text verbatim, this indicates that they rehearsed it, all three *agreed on the story to tell you*. They tell the same text to avoid discrepancies between each other. Telling three completely different stories would of course also be possible, but immediately obvious as untrustworthy.

Comment: Great answer. "You know they're lying" in this context could be paraphrased to "You know something's fishy." And one other key element is that we are talking about "three sources", not three random strangers on the street.

Answer (score 1):

Look at it this way. If three people are telling you the same thing *word for word,* they are "plagiarizing." Or to be more exact, two of them are probably plagiarizing the third.

If that's the case, they are not telling you the same story *independently.* Instead, two are following the lead of the third, and the "third" is probably not telling the truth.

Comment: The "third" *may* still be telling the truth, but the fact that the other two copied their story word-for-word raises suspicions about all three.